# Restricting scripts to subsets of users

Tags: perl, bash, unix, hidden

Suppose I have a perl (or python) script that does something highly secretive; I'd only want to allow certain users to actually be able to use the script.   Currently, I gain this functionality by maintaining a read-only text file called `allowedUsers.txt` and check with the following:

```
my $username = `whoami`; 
my %allowedUsers; 
open ALLOWED_USERS, "allowedUsers.txt"; 
while(<ALLOWED_USERS>) { 
    $allowedUsers{$_} = 1; 
}
if($allowedUsers{$username} != 1) {
    die "Sorry, user $username does not have access.\n"; 
}
```

This works just fine, however since the script is necessarily readable (otherwise Perl itself would not be able to execute it), nothing is stopping people from simply making a copy of the script, commenting out this section of code, and then running their "hacked" version to circumvent the identity check!

Is there a better way to achieve the restriction of script execution to a subset of users?  For instance, can I have perl code that is not readable but somehow executable by everyone?

Comment: The cat & pipe in `open ALLOWED_USERS, "cat allowedUsers.txt |";` are useless. It's much more legible to write `open(ALLOWED_USERS, "allowedUsers.txt);`

Comment: You do realize that if a user can copy the script and use it, that also means that they have permission on your system to access any data that you are trying to hide from them. In other words, this is ["security by obscurity"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only allow a certain [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_security#User_groups) of users to read/execute your script, and put the relevant users in this group.

EDIT: more precisely:

- create a group named, for instance `trusted_users` with your preferred user management tool
- add the authorized users to this group
- set the script's group with [chgrp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chgrp): `chgrp trusted_users my_script.pl`
- set its permissions with [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod): `chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o= my_script.pl` (the owner may read, write, execute; the group members may read and execute; the others can do nothing)

Answer (score 2):

The script checks if it can run and exits if it cannot, but having executable permission implies read permission for the script and so users can simply copy it, remove that silly check and run it.

Create a group of users, and allow only users from that group to read and execute that file. Then you simply add users you want to grant this privilege to that group and voilà! For an example, see [Unix - File Permission / Access Modes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm).